# ¿Cómo retornar un valor a un blade que será enviado por mail sin view( 'nombre.vista' , compact('valorRetornado'))? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, backend, blade

quiero retornar algunos datos de una consulta eloquent a una vista que tiene por finalidad ser enviada por email, por lo que no necesito renderizar la vista de forma

```
return view( 'mails.booking-message' , compact('ultimoHuesped'))
```

según la documentación de laravel se puede enviar una collección de la forma

```
$ultimoHuesped = guest::last();
View::make('mails.booking-message', $ultimoHuesped);
```

pero al intentarlo me da error $ultimoHuesped is undefined, la vista está asi:

```
<p>Hola!! <strong>{{$ultimoHuesped->first_name}}</strong></p>
```

Comment: Podrías decirnos con qué motivo quieres hacer eso? Danos más detalles de tu problema, por qué necesitas hacer eso?

Comment: ahí edité la pregunta!

Comment: Podrías subir el código para ver cómo estás enviando el email?

Comment: el mail lo puedo enviar de manera correcta, sólo que ahora quiero personalizar ese mail con los datos de la ultima persona que llene un formulario. Para eso hago la consulta al ultimo registro y quiero pasarle ese dato a la vista, pero aun no encuentro la forma correcta de hacerlo, a pesar de que podria hacer un `return view('mail.booking-message', compact('ultimoHuesped'))` no quiero enviar una vista que no renderizaré

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la forma de hacerlo, para enviar datos al blade que será enviado como mail tuve que declarar los parámetros en el método Mail que estoy utilizando, asi que quedó mas o menos así:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\BookingMessage;

   public function store(Request $request)
{

  $guestEmail = $request->email; //mail del huesped
  $newGuest = guest::create($request->all());//colección del ultimo registro guardado
  $lastBooking = guest::latest()->first(); //coleccion del ultimo registro guardado

  Mail::to($guestEmail)->send(new BookingMessage($newBooking, $newGuest));//al metodo le paso los parametros
  return redirect()->route('front.reservation'); //redireccion a la vista despues de enviar el correo
}
```

y el controlador que envia el mail quedó:

```
class BookingMessage extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $guestData; //propiedad publica para utilizar
public $bookingData; //propiedad publica para utilizar

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($newBooking, $newGuest) //se reciben los parametros enviados del controlador 
{
    $this->bookingData = $newBooking; //los declaro en la propiedad publica
    $this->guestData = $newGuest; //los declaro en la propiedad publica
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('booking-san-marcos@noreply.cl')
    ->view('mails.booking-message');
}
```

}

y finalmente lo utilizo en el codigo de la vista

```
<p>Hola <strong>{{$guestData->first_name}}</strong> !!</p>
                  <p>Gracias por reservar en Residencial San Marcos, tu reserva es la N° <strong>{{$bookingData->id}}</strong> y está pendiente de confirmación. Personal de nuestro equipo se contactara con usted
                  , le mantendremos informado.</p>
                  <table>
                    <thead>
                      <th>N° pieza</th>
                      <th>llegada</th>
                      <th>Ida</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$bookingData->room_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$bookingData->start_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{$bookingData->end_date}}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia

`$ultimoHuesped = guest::last();`

por

`$ultimoHuesped = guest::lastest()->first();`

Así obtendras el ultimo elemento del modelo **guest** ordenado por el **created_at**

Comment: gracias pude obtener el ultimo registro, pero sigo sin poder utilizar el valor en la vista :/

Comment: copia el resultado de ````dd($ultimoHuesped)````

Answer (score 0):

Hola utiliza el helper render() de laraver

```
$html = view('mails.booking-message')->with(compact('ultimoHuesped'))->render();
```

Esto te regresara el html de la vista.